# Build electron as exe on macbook m1

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

I trying to build an electron with an exe installer on macOS with a MacBook Pro with an m1. I already tried different packages like electron-packager, electron-forge, but unfortunately, none of my tries worked. Did anyone has a solution to build an electron version with an exe on macOS.
My latest approach looked like, but when I start and after more then 30 minute it still do no finish.

`yarn run electron-forge make --arch=x64 --platform=win32`

The current code could be found [here](https://github.com/rogi-sh/defichain-income).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We using [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration.html) for packaging electron app on Windows&MacOS(x86_x64/arm etc.), and you can try it.

add some config in package.json, like this:

```json
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.yourappid",
    "productName": "your-product-name",
    "asar": false, 
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        "pkg"
      ],
      "entitlements": "entitlements.mac.plist"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "zip",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "msi",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
```

then run npm command like this:

```sh
# add package in your project
npm install --save-dev electron-builder
npm run dist # or 'npx electron-builder'
```

If you perfer using 'shelljs', create a file 'dist.js', and content:

```
const { exec, rm } = require('shelljs');
exec('electron-builder');
```

and then run node command

```sh
npm install --save-dev shelljs
node dist.js
```

More detail for config you can read offical doc of electron-builder.

Answer (score 1):

electron-builder 23.0.3 and flag `--universal` work for me on Macbook M1 2021

Comment: This works great, thank you so much. However, I couldn't find `--universal` flag in documentation. Can you please share a link to docs?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. `npx electron-builder --win --x64`

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into it and failed (building Apple Silicon, Apple Intel and Windows distributables from M1 Mac). I ended up setting up VMs that I use for building the distributables, and testing also.

Comment: could you share how you have set up your VM on M1?

Comment: I set it up on my Proxmox server, I can't really help you there. I guess it's better if it run on a x86 CPU anyhow.

Comment: hey @Pierre P I could finally get it done, I'll test and add an answer.